# The omission of conjunction is strange in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

> When the classes were over, they came out in different groups, played games and ran races.

Is the sentence correct? Don't we need to use 'and' or ; instead of , ?

Or, shouldn't we change 'played...ran' to 'playing...running'?

Comment: It's a list. They didn't use an Oxford Comma, which would be placed before the and. **When X, they Y, Z, and W.** Y, Z, and W are sentence fragments that share the subject they.

Comment: Grammatically, it's not incorrect as it stands. However, there is a sequentiality (they came out and then did A and B) meaning that this is better not treated as a simple list. I'd use both a comma and an 'and' to mark this: 'When the classes were over, they came out in different groups, and played games and ran races.'

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct as is: **they came out, played games and ran races.** Don't let the prepositional phrase (in different groups) throw you off.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the sentence is a List, breaking down three things that happened *when the classes were over*. **And** takes the place of a comma between the penultimate and final item in a list.

*Were*, *came*, *played* and *ran* are all using the Past Tense. The suggestion is that there were only two different groups, with one group agreeing *to play games* and the other group agreeing *to run races*.

If the groups broke themselves down into subgroups, each playing different games and running different races, then there would be ample reason to use the participle (as I have in this explanation).